# Bash completion function on various OSs: problem with @ while completing hosts

Tags: linux, bash, macos, solaris

I'm writing a function that mimics the `ssh` command host completion; the main difference being that it uses the hosts of the `xyz.com` domain found in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` for the completion.

Here is the function:

```sh
_xyzssh() {
    COMPREPLY=()

    local arg="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"

    [[ $arg != -* ]] || return 0

    [ -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts ] || return 0

    local -a known_hosts
    read -d '' -a known_hosts < <(awk '{
        n = split($1,arr,",");
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            if (arr[i] ~ /\.xyz\.com$/)
                print arr[i] 
    }' ~/.ssh/known_hosts)

    if [[ $arg == *@* ]]
    then
        known_hosts=( ${known_hosts[@]/#/${arg%%@*}@} )
    fi

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${known_hosts[*]}" -- $arg) )

    return 0
}
complete -F _xyzssh xyzssh
```

This code works fine in Linux (bash 4.2) but it has a weird behavior in macOS (bash 3.2). For example, when I type:

`xyzssh -X user@server` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

- On Linux it completes with: `xyzssh -X user@server.xyz.com`
- On macOS it "doubles" the username: `xyzssh -X useruser@server.xyz.com`

I'm guessing that there is something fishy with the `@` because when I type:

`xyzssh -X user\@server` <kbd>Tab</kbd>

It completes correctly on both Linux **and** macOS.

<s>**Is there a way to fix this behavior on macOS?**</s> *fixed: see accepted answer below*

---

###### Update

Just found out about `COMP_WORDBREAKS`, which contains `@` in macOS while in Linux it doesn't.

I can fix the issue when I set `COMP_WORDBREAKS="${COMP_WORDBREAKS//@}"` in the shell, but making the change resilient is not that easy in macOS (exporting this setting in my `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` doesn't seem to work)...

---

###### Update

I got other issues, with Solaris (bash 4.4) this time, in which `${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}` doesn't even contain the `user@` part when the completion function is called... <s>I' m still investigating how to fix it</s>. *fixed: see accepted answer below*

---

<sup>*It's my first time writing a completion function so I might be missing something obvious.*</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>*Taking the path of answering my own question*</sub>

`COMPREPLY` needs to be populated differently depending on the presence of `@` in `COMP_WORDBREAKS`.

For example, when the user type `ssh user@server` <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

- if `@` ***is not*** in `COMP_WORDBREAKS` then `COMPREPLY` should look like:

```
COMPREPLY=( "user@server.xyz.com" "user@server-bis.xyz.com" )
```

- if `@` ***is*** in `COMP_WORDBREAKS` then `COMPREPLY` should look like:

```
COMPREPLY=( "@server.xyz.com" "@server-bis.xyz.com" )
```

A solution for making the completion function compatible with both cases is to add the right prefix after finding the matching hosts list:

<sub>**Update:** fixed Solaris bash 4.4 issue</sub>

```sh
_xyzssh() {
    COMPREPLY=()

    local curr="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    local prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"

    [[ $curr == -* ]] && return 0

    [ -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts ] || return 0

    local -a known_hosts
    IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a known_hosts < <(awk '{
      n = split($1,arr,",");
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
          if (arr[i] ~ /\.xyz\.com$/)
            print arr[i]
    }' ~/.ssh/known_hosts)

    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${known_hosts[*]}" -- "${curr#*@}") )

    if [[ $curr == *@* || $prev == @ ]]
    then
        if [[ $COMP_WORDBREAKS == *@* ]]
        then
            COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]/#/@}" )
        else
            COMPREPLY=( "${COMPREPLY[@]/#/${curr%%@*}@}" )
        fi
    fi

    return 0
}
complete -F _xyzssh xyzssh
```

---

###### Debug information

Here is what I get in `COMP_WORDS` when I type `xyzssh -X user@server` <kbd>Tab</kbd> on the different OSs:

- redhat 7 (bash 4.2, `@` **not** present in `COMP_WORDBREAKS`)

```sh
COMP_WORDS=( "xyzssh" "-X" "user@server" )
```

- macOS (bash 3.2, `@` present in `COMP_WORDBREAKS`)

```sh
COMP_WORDS=( "xyzssh" "-X" "user@server" )
```

- solaris 11.4 (bash 4.4, `@` present in `COMP_WORDBREAKS`)

```sh
COMP_WORDS=( "xyzssh" "-X" "user" "@" "server" )
```